# Prove that $n|(n+1)^n - 1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $n$ be and integer and $n>0$. Prove that $n|(n+1)^n - 1$

Any help with this problem would be appreciated :)

Comment: Is exponent also to the whole fraction ?

Comment: Advice to all students: There is no equation more worth learning than $x^n-y^n = (x-y)(x^{n-1} + x^{n-2} y + \cdots + xy^{n-2} + y^{n-1})$.

Comment: @slade I'm not sure,  $e^{i\theta }=\cos \theta + i\sin \theta$ is pretty up there :)

Answer (score 5):

$$(1+n)^a=1+\binom a1n+\binom a2n^2+\cdots+n^a\equiv1\pmod n$$ for any integer $a\ge0,n$

Answer (score 2):

Using modulo is just straight forward.

$ n \equiv 0 \mod n \implies (n+1) \equiv 1 \mod n $. Raise it to any power $ k \in \mathbb{N}$. 
$(n+1)^k \equiv 1 \mod n$, you have the result.